# AngularJS calling array with function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller

i'm trying to create a  context menu with angularjs.when users click right , context menu will open , however context menu may change according to user level,therefore i want to call 'mycontext' menu array with function but it does not work when i call it with function in controller in angular.

i want to call my context menu with 'launch()' function.

```
<a ng-context-menu="launch(y)">Open Context Menu</a>
```

My controller :

```
controller: function($scope) {

  $scope.launch = function (m) {

    // .......................

    $scope.mycontext = [
      [
        'opt1',
        function () {
          console.log("buy");
        }
      ], [
        'opt2',
        function () {
          console.log("sell");
        }
      ]
    ];

  };

}
```

How can i run it with calling function?

Comment: look a this fiddle -> [http://jsfiddle.net/D5MHW/]

Answer (score 0):

I think you want an array with JSON objects.

```
var test = [
      {
        someValue:'tada',
        someFunct: function() {
         alert('tada!');   
        }
      },
      {
        someValue:'something else',
        someFunct: function() {
          alert('something else here');
        }
     }];
```

I made an example with simple jQuery, but it should easily be adopted to your Angular code. http://jsfiddle.net/fan4Lwu4/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to invoke the functions inside `$scope.mycontext` array, you can write a loop and invoke the functions.

```js
angular
  .module('demo', [])
  .controller('DefaultController', DefaultController);
  
  function DefaultController() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.run = run;
    
    function run() {
      vm.mycontext = [
      [
       'opt1',
        function () {
          console.log("buy");
        }
      ], 
      [
        'opt2',
        function () {
          console.log("sell");
        }
      ]
    ];
    
    for (var i = 0; i < vm.mycontext.length; i++) {
     vm.mycontext[i][1]();
    }
    }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demo">
  <div ng-controller="DefaultController as ctrl">
    <button type="button" ng-click="ctrl.run()">Run</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or use Immediately Invoked Function Expressions if you can change the array itself.

```js
angular
  .module('demo', [])
  .controller('DefaultController', DefaultController);
  
  function DefaultController() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.run = run;
    
    function run() {
      vm.mycontext = [
      [
       'opt1',
        (function () {
          console.log("buy");
        })()
      ], 
      [
        'opt2',
        (function () {
          console.log("sell");
        })()
      ]
    ];
    }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demo">
  <div ng-controller="DefaultController as ctrl">
    <button type="button" ng-click="ctrl.run()">Run</button>
  </div>
</div>
```